# Cmake linking thrift

Tags: linux, cmake, thrift

I am trying to link thrift in CMake so that I can compile my test application.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(TestApp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(TestApp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestApp -lthrift --static -pthread )
```

Here is a simple test application including the thrift headers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TSocket.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TBufferTransports.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TTransportUtils.h>
#include <thrift/stdcxx.h>

using namespace apache::thrift;
using namespace apache::thrift::protocol;
using namespace apache::thrift::transport;

int main() {

    std::cout << "BlaBlaBla" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I am trying to compile the snippet shown above I am prompted with a linker error:

```
/opt/JetBrains/apps/CLion/ch-0/181.5087.36/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/user/Documents/Projects/TestApp/cmake-build-debug --target TestApp -- -j 2
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable TestApp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lthrift
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/TestApp.dir/build.make:95: TestApp] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/TestApp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:80: CMakeFiles/TestApp.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: TestApp] Error 2
```

However, the thrift libraries are definitely installed.
How can I link fix this issue and link them correctly in the CMake file?

Comment: I actually fixed the problem. Seems like installing thrift via pacman didn't work properly. I cloned the thrift repository from github, and followed the build guide there. After a `sudo make install` the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got solved by cloning the thrift repository from github https://github.com/apache/thrift

Then I simply followed the build instruction there.
I did run `./bootstrap.sh` and `./configure` followed by `make` and then `sudo make install`.
Now the linker recognizes the `-lthrift` flag.